# HTML+JavaScript: How to highlight a row on click of a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using below code to generate a dynamic table-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.write("<table id=appTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>");
        document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Action</th></tr>");
        for (row = 1; row < 5; row++) {

            document.write("<tr>");

            for (col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
                if(col == 1) {
                    document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' /></td>");
                }
                if(col == 2) {
                    document.write("<td width='140'>Name</td>");
                }
                if(col == 3) {
                    document.write("<td width='200'>Location</td>");
                }
                if(col == 4) {
                    document.write("<td><button type='button'>select</button></td>");
                }
            }

            document.write("</tr>")

        }

        document.write("</table>")
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the select button is clicked the table row should highlight the entire row.
Any idea how to implement it in `javascript` & `css` ?

Comment: jquery will hlep, is it allowed ?

Comment: Yes, do you use jQuery?

Comment: Actually I'm not much familiar with `jquery`. Can't it be done in javascript ?

Comment: Why you are using two nested loops? You don't need second one - you can remove all "if"s and whole for cycle

Comment: @areim yes we can remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight row when clicked on button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075805/highlight-row-when-clicked-on-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go! Add a function to your button `onclick` while creating it and write a function as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fevvmc8z/)**

So changed button html before appending will be

```
document.write("<td><button type='button' onclick='highlight(this)'>select</button></td>")
                                          ^^^^^Add this
```

and a function

```
function highlight(ctrl){
   var parent=ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
   parent.style.background='red';
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To remove previous selected on click of other below is one of the approach you can opt to:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fevvmc8z/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.backChange{
    background:red;
}
```

**JS**

***Scenario 1***

```
function highlight(ctrl){
   var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('tr'); //get all the tr elements
   for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        elements[i].className=''; //clear the className from all the tr elements
   var parent=ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
   parent.className="backChange"; //add ClassName to only this element's parent tr

}
```

***Scenario 2***

Now If you have `classList` that are already there in `tr` and you just want to add or remove one particular `class` which changes its `style` then you can do it as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fevvmc8z/2/)**

```
function highlight(ctrl){
   var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        elements[i].classList.remove('backChange'); //remove one particular class from list of classNames in that element
   var parent=ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
   parent.classList.add("backChange");//Add that particular class to classList of element's parent tr
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Without using Class and applying `inline styles` you can try as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fevvmc8z/4/)**

```
function highlight(ctrl){
   var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        elements[i].style.background=''; //remove background color
   var parent=ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
   parent.style.background="red";//add it to specific element.

}
```

Comment: Thanks @GuruprasadRao your code is working but in this way if I click another row select button then that row is also being highlighted. If we can erase the previous row colour and highlight the new one then that would be very helpful.

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty updated answer.. check and let me know!!

Comment: I don't know but with CSS it's not working. Earlier code was working fine.
It's not giving any error in console. Simply not working

Comment: did you check the demo??

Comment: yeah in try it editor (w3schools) also it's working fine.
can we do it without css class ?

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty.. updated answer with very first approach!! Check and let me know!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84663/discussion-between-anurag-chakraborty-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by adding an onclick function to your button:

```
<button type='button' onclick='highlight(this)'>
```

And then include the function before your loop:

```
function highlight(button) {
    button.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'highlight';
    // the first parentNode is the td
    // the second is the tr, 
    // then you add a class of highlight to the row
}
```

And add the css for the highlight:

```
.highlight {background:red;}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mskwbo93/)

Comment: Could be a user called simi tkd - downvotes seemed to happen as his answer was deleted

Comment: Any ways to visit his profile!! Even he might have got reputation down!

Comment: from my side too +1 !! We have valid answers!!

Comment: Your code works perfectly. But how can we revert/toggle it? Like if we click again select button of another row previous coloured row will be gone and this new row will be highlighted. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: you need to check to see if the classname is already added: http://jsfiddle.net/mskwbo93/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following snippet:

```js
function hightLight(ele)
{
    ele.parentElement.parentElement.className = "highlight";
}

document.write("<table id=appTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>");
document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Action</th></tr>");
for (row=1; row<5; row++)
{
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (col=1; col<=4; col++) 
  {
     if(col==1)
     {                       document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' /></td>");
      }
       if(col==2)
       document.write("<td width='140'>Name</td>");
       if(col==3)
       document.write("<td width='200'>Location</td>");
       if(col==4)
       document.write("<td><button onclick='hightLight(this)' type='button'>select</button></td>");
    }
       document.write("</tr>");
  }
       document.write("</table>");
```

```css
.highlight
{
  background-color:yellow;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using a `button` here and rather use the `checkboxes` which you already have. If you use a `button` to select a row, then how would you de-select it? You can then use the `button`s to fire up actions on the selected row.

From a raw Javascript perspective (i.e. without using any library like jQuery etc.), you can work your algorithm like this:

1. Find all checkboxes in the table,
2. Bind a "change" event to all these checkboxes,
3. If the checkbox is `checked` then select the row by changing its parent's (`td`) parent (`tr`) background color.

Putting this together:

```js
var chk = document.querySelectorAll("table input[type=checkbox]");

for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    chk[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        selectRow(this);
    });
}
function selectRow(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
        elem.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    } else {
        elem.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Location 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
            <td>Location 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 3</td>
            <td>Location 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you caan use JQuery **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jgh84dy/1/)**

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("tr").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    });
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlight {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_table_id').on('click', 'td', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').css({'background-color': 'red'});
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i agree this is not pure javascript . JQuery comment: I register function after your code. If somebody clicks on td, function searches parent 'tr' element and highlights it to red