# Background color is not changing after adding CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already have an answer of highlighting a row of a table in this link:
[HTML+JavaScript: How to highlight a row on click of a button in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653389/htmljavascript-how-to-highlight-a-row-on-click-of-a-button-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment51252617_31653389)

I'm using the below code to generate a dynamic table and the `highlight` function to highlight a row, but when I add some CSS it's unable to change the color of the row. Why?

```js
function highlight(ctrl) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  console.log(elements[1].style.background);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.background = ''; //remove background color
  var parent = ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
  parent.style.background = '#E9FFAA'; //add it to specific element.

}
document.write("<table id=appTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>");
document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Action</th></tr>");
for (row = 1; row < 5; row++) {

  document.write("<tr>");

  for (col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
    if (col == 1) {
      document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' /></td>");
    }
    if (col == 2) {
      document.write("<td width='140'>Name</td>");
    }
    if (col == 3) {
      document.write("<td width='200'>Location</td>");
    }
    if (col == 4) {
      document.write("<td><button type='button' onclick='highlight(this)'>select</button></td>");
    }
  }

  document.write("</tr>")

}

document.write("</table>")
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0.5px;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  text-align: left;
  color: #232323;
  font: normal 13px/18px"Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 7px 6px 7px 6px;
}
td {
  color: #232323;
  font: normal 13px/18px"Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.scrollableTable {
  height: 380px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code?

Comment: Actually the html code is in that link. I didn't add it here because it will increase the size

Comment: Please include the full code in this question. Each question needs to be self contained.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want color for your row add your table row on your css
for example

```
tr
{ background-color: green;
  }
```

and remove `background-color:white;` on your td

```
td{
color:#232323;
font: normal 13px/18px "Open Sans",helvetica,sans-serif;
//background-color:white;
border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `highlight` function is currently adding and removing the `background-color` from the `tr`s. This is working, the problem is that you are setting the `background-color` of the `td`s to `white` in CSS which is hiding the `background-color` applied to the `tr` that contains them. To fix, remove `background-color: white;` from the `td`.

```js
function highlight(ctrl) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  console.log(elements[1].style.background);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.background = ''; //remove background color
  var parent = ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;
  parent.style.background = '#E9FFAA'; //add it to specific element.

}
document.write("<table id=appTable border=1 style=margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;>");
document.write("<tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Action</th></tr>");
for (row = 1; row < 5; row++) {

  document.write("<tr>");

  for (col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
    if (col == 1) {
      document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='mapCheck' name='myTextEditBox' /></td>");
    }
    if (col == 2) {
      document.write("<td width='140'>Name</td>");
    }
    if (col == 3) {
      document.write("<td width='200'>Location</td>");
    }
    if (col == 4) {
      document.write("<td><button type='button' onclick='highlight(this)'>select</button></td>");
    }
  }

  document.write("</tr>")

}

document.write("</table>")
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0.5px;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  text-align: left;
  color: #232323;
  font: normal 13px/18px"Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 7px 6px 7px 6px;
}
td {
  color: #232323;
  font: normal 13px/18px"Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.scrollableTable {
  height: 380px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```